# Disable a day in a datepicker that is not in the list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a variable that will receive some data, specifically the day of the week and something else.

```
let wTime = [{"day":"Mon"},{"day":"Tue"},{"day":"Wed"},{"day":"Fri"},{"day":"Sat"},{"day":"Sun"}]
```

I also have a bootstrap datepicker, and in it I need to determine which day is not in the `wTime` variable and disable this day.

How can i do this? Specifically, there is no `Th` day right now, and for now I manually disable it using `daysOfWeekDisabled: '4'`

```js
let wTime = [{"day":"Mon"},{"day":"Tue"},{"day":"Wed"},{"day":"Fri"},{"day":"Sat"},{"day":"Sun"}]
let restaurantReserve = {
    init: function() {
        let _self = this;
        let today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us',{day:'numeric', month:'short'}).split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d',
            daysOfWeekDisabled: '4'
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });

        $("#reservation-date").datepicker("setDate", today);
    },
    setError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
    },
    unSetError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
    }
}

restaurantReserve.init();
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #e3e5e8;
    color: #747b8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
  <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">click</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make a day checker?  If you want to dynamically get rid of a day, simply check to see which day is missing and set that to your `daysOfWeekDisabled:`

You could do something like this:

```
let wTime = [{"day":"Tue"},{"day":"Fri"},{"day":"Sat"},{"day":"Sun"}]
let dayCheck = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
let dayNumbers = ''
let disabledDays = dayCheck.filter(y => wTime.map(x => x['day']).every(x => x !== y)).forEach(y => dayNumbers += dayCheck.indexOf(y))

console.log(dayNumbers.split('').join(', '))
```

EDIT: One issue that has not been clarified is where is the user interacting with `wTime`.  As in, how are you getting the user interaction to decide which day should be omitted?  This solution is assuming `wTime` is somehow being modified through a user interaction.  If that part is already decided, then this should work.  If you need help with actually setting `wTime` up to be accessible to user engagement, then we'll need more code.

Full code would look like this:

```
let wTime = [{"day":"Tue"},{"day":"Fri"},{"day":"Sat"},{"day":"Sun"}]
let dayCheck = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
let dayNumbers = ''
let disabledDays = dayCheck.filter(y => wTime.map(x => x['day']).every(x => x !== y)).forEach(y => dayNumbers += dayCheck.indexOf(y))

let restaurantReserve = {
    init: function() {
        let _self = this;
        let today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us',{day:'numeric', month:'short'}).split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d',
            daysOfWeekDisabled: dayNumbers.split('').join(', ')
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });

        $("#reservation-date").datepicker("setDate", today);
    },
    setError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
    },
    unSetError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
    }
}

restaurantReserve.init();
```

Comment: can you include a working snippet? you might consider .forEach instead of map and then push the value into an array. currently you assume that only 1 day can be disabled. also not sure but the OP was using a digit to disable the day rather than the Day string (ie Mon)

Comment: Updated it and you were right, I rushed it a bit.  It works fine now, and I tried to make it as concise as possible.

Comment: tried to start, all days work

Comment: I just checked documentation - the format needs to be a string that is comma delimited with numbers.  I have updated my code quickly to reflect that.  I may need to refactor but this should work.  EDIT:  It will work now, the index of the days should be correct according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Enhancing your current function with an Enum that gives us each day correlating to a number. Then simply filter that enum with the wTime array to find the missing days and disable them.

```js
let wTime = [{"day":"Mon"},{"day":"Tue"},{"day":"Wed"},{"day":"Fri"},{"day":"Sat"},{"day":"Sun"}]
let wTimeEnum = {'Mon':'1', 'Tue':'2', 'Wed':'3','Thur':'4', 'Fri':'5', 'Sat':'6', 'Sun':'0'};
let restaurantReserve = {
    init: function() {
        let _self = this;
        let today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us',{day:'numeric', month:'short'}).split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

        $('#reservation-date').datepicker({
            startDate: '+0d',
            daysOfWeekDisabled: Object.keys(wTimeEnum).filter((k) => wTime.every((d) => d.day != k)).map((k) => wTimeEnum[k])
            //daysOfWeekDisabled: ['4']
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            const arDate = e.date.toString().split(' ');
            let input = $('[name="RestaurantReservationForm[date]"]');
            input.val(arDate[3] + '-' + (e.date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + arDate[2]);
            _self.unSetError(input);
            $('#reservation-date .js-value').text(arDate[2] + ' ' + arDate[1]);
        });

        $("#reservation-date").datepicker("setDate", today);
    },
    setError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).addClass('btn-error');
    },
    unSetError: function(ob) {
        $('#' + ob.data('btnId')).removeClass('btn-error');
    }
}

restaurantReserve.init();
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-fourth {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #e3e5e8;
    color: #747b8b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-fourth " id="reservation-date" data-date=">">
  <span class="icon br-calender"></span> <span class="js-value">click</span>
</a>
```

Comment: here for some reason `Sun` also disables

Comment: Made an edit to address this. the map alone was returning false and equating to 0.. now filter first then map returns an array of just the disabled days

Comment: Upvote to @tstrand66 for the time and effort, plus he put me in line on my code earlier :D

Comment: @tstrand66 also, that 1k is going to look nice by your name!  Good luck!

Comment: Lol, thank you sir. always enjoy seeing multiple answers to a question. diversity of thought is so important on a site like this.

Comment: For sure, and seeing the way people approach things is probably one of the coolest things about a site like this and programming in general.  So many fun way to achieve the same solution.